# Getting the View's center when initialing a variable

Tags: swift

I'm very new to Swift and trying to make a simple application to learn.
I'm trying to setup on screen a UISlider and set it in the middle of the screen, the problem is that the view is probably isn't ready yet.
I tried to do something like this:

```
> private let bullsEyeSlider: UISlider = {
>         let slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX,y:100, width: 500, height: 20))
>         slider.minimumValue = 0
>         slider.maximumValue = 100
>         return slider
>     }()
```

to get the center of the view (the x center at least) but of course it can't work.
I'm trying to think of something else to do but other than just setting up the slider after the view is initialised I can't think of anything else.
Tried to search the web but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewDidLayoutSubviews method of the view controller add:

```
bullsEyeSlider.center = view.center
```

Comment: Thanks! I heard about a lazy var, which I tried doing right now and it did worked too. Is there a preferred way to do it or they both ok?

Comment: lazy var will still fail in some cases I had been using this method to set the frames correctly and it works perfectly fine all the time

Comment: How should I initialise the slider if I center it after the view is loaded? It needs a CGFloat to be initialised

Comment: you can initialize the same way you did and adjust the frame properly using this method